# How to prevent a Winforms control from listening to the keyboard 

Tags: winforms, controls, click, key, enter

For a certain inputform, I'd like to make it possible to do input with the keyboard.  I know how to read the keys through KeyPressed and KeyUp, but the problem is that when a control has got the focus and the user presses the Enter key, that control receives the a Click event.  Is it possible to prevent that behaviour ?  Or is it possible to know if a Click Event was fired by the mouse or by the keyboard ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help? From [Microsoft Knowledge Base](http://kbalertz.com/955938/Remove-ability-keyboard-trigger-button-click.aspx)

> Move the Button's code from the button.Click() to a button.MouseClick()

Answer (score 2):

This would be easier if you could describe the situation and exact behaviour you want... :)

You can set:

```
Form.KeyPreview = True
```

This sends Key Events to the Form first, and then to the Control. This gives you the opportunity to catch Key Events on the form and 'cancel' them:

```
e.Handled = True
```

[More info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx)

Also make sure you haven't set the AcceptButton for the Form!

Answer (score 0):

You can also listen for keyboard events and filter out keys.